# Register Alarm Receiver

Tags: java, android, receiver

I try to register a broadcast receiver in my mainActivity (because I must have non static receiver in order to call a function of my mainActivity)

For the moment the receiver do not receive.... What should I do ?

mainActivity.java

```
public class mainActivity
{
    private BroadcastReceiver alarm;

    ...

    Intent startIntent = new Intent("WhatEverYouWant");
    PendingIntent startPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, startIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, startPIntent);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    this.alarm = new AlarmReceiver();
    registerReceiver(this.alarm, filter);

}

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{    
    public AlarmReceiver ()
    {
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
         doRestartApp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Intent must be have the same name as the IntentFilter...
Now it works !

```
public class mainActivity
{
    private BroadcastReceiver alarm;

    ...

    Intent startIntent = new Intent("MESSAGE_PROCESSED");
    PendingIntent startPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, startIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, startPIntent);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("MESSAGE_PROCESSED");
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    this.alarm = new AlarmReceiver();
    registerReceiver(this.alarm, filter);

}

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{    
    public AlarmReceiver ()
    {
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
         doRestartApp();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested this and worked!. Great answer